# Laravel Valet Timeout on Mac Sierra

Tags: php, laravel, virtualhost, laravel-5.4, laravel-valet

Laravel's valet has been working fine till today and now all of sudden I started receiving Timeout error for all of my applications. I completely uninstalled valet and installed again. After installation, I parked my websites and now all I get is "It works!". No idea what is wrong!

Tried all suggestions on below link

https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/298#issuecomment-274800253.

Comment: Which version of Valet are you running?

Comment: I'm using Valet 2.0.4

Comment: I completely removed valet and install again. Now I get 502 Bad Gateway

Comment: @SaravananSampathkumar If you are geting 502 then must be PHP version problem.

Comment: `php -v` in terminal?

Comment: @SaravananSampathkumar did you fix this? It just happened to me.